# Is it possible to programmatically decorate a function/method at runtime?

Tags: python, decorator

Let's say I have a python function that returns a function

```
def get_function():
    @some_decorator
    def some_function():
        // some code
    return some_function
```

Instead, I want something like:

```
def get_function():
    @some_decorator
    def some_function():
        // some code

    if some_condition:
         return some_function                    # Return some_function() with @some_decorator
    else:
         return some_function_without_decorator  # Return some_function() without @some_decorator
```

Comment: It is important to understand, using the `@` syntax *is* programmatically decorating a function at runtime, although, it isn't convenient if you want to do it conditionally. Instead, see the answer already posted - the @ syntax is just sugar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decorator simply returns the function below it wrapped around the decorator's function. In other words, this:

```
@some_decorator
def some_function():
    # some code
```

Is equivalent to:

```
some_function = some_decorator(some_function)
```

Which means that you can programmatically "decorate" the function by writing:

```
if some_condition:
    some_function = some_decorator(some_function)
```

Comment: There's no need for scare quotes here, that *is* decorating the function.

Comment: Right, it's just not how someone who's beginning with Python thinks about decorators.